# Get performance of submitted changelist in Perforce

Tags: perforce

We want to do some analysis on our past project and I would like to gather information on some changelist submissions that happend a few month's ago. How can I query or parse that information?

I'm looking for information like:

- Submission time (x files submitted in x amount of time)
- Retries
- Load on server

Comment: What information? The "performance" of what?

Comment: Hey @Samwise tried to update the question, I'm mostly interested in the check-in time, how long it took for a changelist to get submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perforce server performance information is in the server logs; the format depends on how your server is configured, but by default you should generally see performance tracking output for any operation that takes significant time to complete, e.g.:

```
Perforce server info:
    2020/10/06 08:15:22 pid 23556 Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 unknown [p4/2016.2/NTX86/1568552] 'user-submit'
--- lapse 66.4s
```

A submit is broken into three phases -- `user-submit`, `dm-SubmitFile`, and `dm-CommitFile`.  The first phase corresponds to the user initiating the operation (filling out the changelist form etc), the second phase is the file transfer, and the third phase is the final commit of the new revisions to the repository.

If you want to do serious analysis of server performance, you probably want to look into structured logging: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/structure-logging-using.html

Comment: Is there a way to see the changelist in that process?

Comment: Not via the log on its own, as far as I know.  I'd do it by correlating the commit time and user/client (which you can get from the log) with `p4 changes`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that works pretty well!